# Possible Bug? Minimum Date UIDatePicker Swift

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

I set the minimum date in the date picker like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        datePicker.minimumDate = NSDate()
}
```

This does prevent the user from rolling back the date, sort of. The user can roll the date dial back but it just snaps back to the current date. The problem is that when this happens, the datetime is set to midnight instead of the current time for any and all future changes and it also executes the event that runs when the date changes. This is a problem when it comes to my code and sliders in my UI. It thinks that the date changed when it did not, yeah it bounces back but it's too late by this point my code runs assuming the date changed.  How do I prevent the user from rolling the dial back at all?

Steps to reproduce:

1) Set minimum date as shown above.

2) Set up an event for date change

3) Set event to print(datePicker.date)

4) Roll Dial forward

5) Roll dial backward beyond current date.

6) Roll dial forward

Notice the time is now permanently set to midnight from this point forward.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix/workaround was to set datePicker.date = NSDate() in the date changed event function.